# CSV >> Tensorflow >> regression (via neural network) model

Tags: python, csv, numpy, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

TLDR; 1) read and convert CSV data to image, 2) create regression model from data. Note that I was very new to python, deep learning, and Stackoverflow in 2016. Please vote to close this. I think it's too outdated.

### Original question below...

Endless Googling has left me better educated on Python and numpy, but still clueless on solving my task. I want to read a CSV of integer/floating point values and predict a value using a neural network. I have found several examples that read the Iris dataset and do classification, but I don't understand how to make them work for regression. Can someone help me connect the dots?

Here is one line of the input:

> 16804,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.490265,0.620805,0.54977,0.869299,0.422268,0.351223,0.33572,0.68308,0.40455,0.47779,0.307628,0.301921,0.318646,0.365993,6135.81

That should be 925 values. The last column is the output. The first is the RowID. Most are binary values because I've already done one-hot encoding. The test files do not have the output/last column. The full training file has around 10M rows. A general MxN solution will do.

Edit: Let's use this sample data since Iris is a classification problem, but note that the above is my real target. I removed the ID column. Let's predict the last column given the 6 other columns. This has 45 rows. (src: [http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/civwar2.dat](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/civwar2.dat))

> 100,1861,5,2,3,5,38
> 112,1863,11,7,4,59.82,15.18
> 113,1862,34,32,1,79.65,2.65
> 90,1862,5,2,3,68.89,5.56
> 93,1862,14,10,4,61.29,17.2
> 179,1862,22,19,3,62.01,8.89
> 99,1861,22,16,6,67.68,27.27
> 111,1862,16,11,4,78.38,8.11
> 107,1863,17,11,5,60.75,5.61
> 156,1862,32,30,2,60.9,12.82
> 152,1862,23,21,2,73.55,6.41
> 72,1863,7,3,3,54.17,20.83
> 134,1862,22,21,1,67.91,9.7
> 180,1862,23,16,4,69.44,3.89
> 143,1863,23,19,4,81.12,8.39
> 110,1862,16,12,2,31.82,9.09
> 157,1862,15,10,5,52.23,24.84
> 101,1863,4,1,3,58.42,18.81
> 115,1862,14,11,3,86.96,5.22
> 103,1862,7,6,1,70.87,0
> 90,1862,11,11,0,70,4.44
> 105,1862,20,17,3,80,4.76
> 104,1862,11,9,1,29.81,9.62
> 102,1862,17,10,7,49.02,6.86
> 112,1862,19,14,5,26.79,14.29
> 87,1862,6,3,3,8.05,72.41
> 92,1862,4,3,0,11.96,86.96
> 108,1862,12,7,3,16.67,25
> 86,1864,0,0,0,2.33,11.63
> 82,1864,4,3,1,81.71,8.54
> 76,1864,1,0,1,48.68,6.58
> 79,1864,0,0,0,15.19,21.52
> 85,1864,1,1,0,89.41,3.53
> 85,1864,1,1,0,56.47,0
> 85,1864,0,0,0,31.76,15.29
> 87,1864,6,5,0,81.61,3.45
> 85,1864,5,5,0,72.94,0
> 83,1864,0,0,0,46.99,2.38
> 101,1864,5,5,0,1.98,95.05
> 99,1864,6,6,0,42.42,9.09
> 10,1864,0,0,0,50,9
> 98,1864,6,6,0,79.59,3.06
> 10,1864,0,0,0,71,9
> 78,1864,5,5,0,70.51,1.28
> 89,1864,4,4,0,59.55,13.48

Let me add that this is a common task, but seems to not be answered by any forums I've read thus I've asked this. I could give you my broken code, but I don't want to waste your time with code that is not functionally correct. Sorry I've asked it this way. I just don't understand the APIs and the documentation doesn't tell me the data types.

Here is the latest code I have that reads the CSV into two ndarrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tensorflow as tf
import csv
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt

# Build Example Data is CSV format, but use Iris data
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import sklearn
def buildDataFromIris():
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    data = np.loadtxt(open("t100.csv.out","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=0)
    labels = np.copy(data)
    labels = labels[:,924]
    print "labels: ", type (labels), labels.shape, labels.ndim
    data = np.delete(data, [924], axis=1)
    print "data: ", type (data), data.shape, data.ndim
```

And here is base code that I want to use. The example this came from wasn't complete either. The APIs in the links below are vague. If I can at least figure out the data types input into DNNRegressor and the others in the docs, I might be able to write some custom code.

```
estimator = DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=[education_emb, occupation_emb],
    hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256])

# Or estimator using the ProximalAdagradOptimizer optimizer with
# regularization.
estimator = DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=[education_emb, occupation_emb],
    hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],
    optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
      learning_rate=0.1,
      l1_regularization_strength=0.001
    ))

# Input builders
def input_fn_train: # returns x, Y
  pass
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train)

def input_fn_eval: # returns x, Y
  pass
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_eval)
estimator.predict(x=x)
```

And then the big question is how to get these to work together.

Here are a few pages I've been looking at.

- Base code that reads CSV and works (classifier):
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/index.html
- Regressor:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#DNNRegressor
  -CSV reading:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#csv-files
- Column embedding:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html
- List of APIs (DNNRegressor, TensorFlowDNNRegressor, LinearRegressor,
  TensorFlowLinearRegressor, TensorFlowRNNRegressor,
  TensorFlowRegressor):
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html

Comment: Can you narrow the problem description?  It appears that the current problems are (1) how to ingest a CSV file in your one-hot format; (2) how to switch from strict classification (enumeration type) to scoring (that float value at the end of the CSV line).

Comment: Could you post your conversion attempt and the resulting (lack of output)?  That would give us a much more focused problem to attack.

Comment: I've simplified the scope because I essentially can read a CSV, but I don't know how to input that into the NN in their desired format.

Comment: It looks like no one knows ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found lower-level Tensorflow pretty hard to figure out in the past as well. And the documentation hasn't been amazing. If you instead focus on getting the hang of `sklearn`, you should find it relatively easy to work with `skflow`. `skflow` is at a much higher level than `tensorflow` and it has almost the same api is `sklearn`.

Now to the answer:

As a regression example, we'll just perform regression on the iris dataset. Now this is a silly idea, but it's just to demonstrate how to use `DNNRegressor`.

## Skflow API

The first time you use a new API, try to use as few parameters as possible. You just want to get something working. So, I propose you can set up a `DNNRegressor` like this:

```
estimator = skflow.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[16, 16])
```

I kept my # hidden units small because I don't have much computational power right now.

Then you give it the training data, `train_X`, and training labels `train_y` and you fit it as follows:

```
estimator.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

This is the standard procedure for all `sklearn` classifiers and regressors and `skflow` just extends `tensorflow` to be similar to `sklearn`. I also set the parameter `steps = 10` so that the training finishes faster when it only runs for 10 iterations.

Now, if you want it to predict on some new data, `test_X`, you do that as follows:

```
pred = estimator.predict(test_X)
```

Again, this is standard procedure for all `sklearn` code. So that's it - `skflow` is so simplified you just need those three lines!

## What's the format of train_X and train_y?

If you aren't too familiar with machine learning, your training data is generally an `ndarray` (matrix) of size M x d where you have M training examples and d features. Your labels are M x 1 (`ndarray` of shape `(M,)`).

So what you have is something like this:

```
Features:   Sepal Width    Sepal Length ...               Labels
          [   5.1            2.5             ]         [0 (setosa)     ]
  X =     [   2.3            2.4             ]     y = [1 (virginica)  ]
          [   ...             ...            ]         [    ....       ]
          [   1.3            4.5             ]         [2 (Versicolour)]
```

(note I just made all those numbers up).

The test data will just be an N x d matrix where you have N test examples. The test examples all need to have d features. The predict function will take in the test data and return to you the test labels of shape N x 1 (`ndarray` of shape `(N,)`)

You didn't supply your .csv file so I'll let you parse the data into that format. Conveniently though, we can use `sklearn.datsets.load_iris()` to get the `X` and `y` we want. It's just

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data 
y = iris.target
```

## Using a Regressor as a Classifier

The output of your `DNNRegressor` will be a bunch of real numbers (like 1.6789). But the iris-dataset has labels 0, 1, and 2 - the integer IDs for Setosa, Versicolour, and Virginia. To perform a classification with this regressor, we will just round it to the nearest label (0, 1, 2). For example, a prediction of 1.6789 will round to 2.

## Working Example

I find I learn the most with a working example. So here's a very simplified working example:

[image]

Feel free to post any further questions as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the response and for providing a complete example. I added some small sample regression data. In the meantime, I'll test this. Also, I'm trying to avoid using TF's build in functions that load sample data because those data structures can not be used. The input must start from numpy arrays, text or binary files. I have now figured out how to read CSV into NDArray. Can I assume that "X = iris.data" is an NDArray?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an ndarray. You can check with `print type(X)`

Comment: The current version of TF requires the feature column. I got this error:    
Traceback (most recent call last):                           
  File "iris_regression.py", line 12, in <module>                      
    estimator = skflow.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[16,16])                  
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: You can fix this by importing `from tensorflow.contrib.learn import infer_real_valued_columns_from_input` and then using `tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X)` as your feature columns. Honestly, I can't figure out what that does from reading the documentation. You can stick with `sklearn` or try other libraries like Keras for neural networks - IMO, they seem to have better documentation and less "weird" parameters. Tensorflow has a very steep learning curve.

Comment: I don't know that we've quite bottomed out on the issue, but I believe that the answer moves OP far enough along top warrant the official "thank you" of 50 points.  I learned much of what I wanted to know with this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a few options. I don't know why it was so difficult to get up and running. First, here is the code based on @user2570465.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow

def buildDataFromIris():
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    return iris.data, iris.target

X, y = buildDataFromIris()
feature_cols = tf.contrib.learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(X)
estimator = skflow.DNNRegressor( feature_columns=feature_cols, hidden_units=[10, 10])
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y)
estimator.fit(X, y, steps=10)

test_preds = estimator.predict(test_X)

def CalculateAccuracy(X, y):
    continuous_predictions = estimator.predict(X)
    closest_class = []
    for pred in continuous_predictions:
        differences = np.array([abs(pred-1), abs(pred-1), abs(pred-1)])
        closest_class.append(np.argmin(differences))

    num_correct = np.sum(closest_class == y)
    accuracy = float(num_correct)/len(y)
    return accuracy

train_accuracy = CalculateAccuracy(train_X, train_y)
test_accuracy = CalculateAccuracy(test_X, test_y)

print("Train accuracy: %f" % train_accuracy)
print("Test accuracy: %f" % test_accuracy)
```

The other solutions built the model from smaller components. Here is a snippet that computes Sig(X*W1+b1)*W2+b2 = Y. Optimizer=Adam, loss=L2, eval=L2 and MSE.

```
x_train = X[:train_size]
y_train = Y[:train_size]
x_val = X[train_size:]
y_val = Y[train_size:]
print("x_train: {}".format(x_train.shape))

x_train = all_x[:train_size]
print("x_train: {}".format(x_train.shape))
# y_train = func(x_train)
# x_val = all_x[train_size:]
# y_val = func(x_val)

# plt.figure(1)
# plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, c='blue', label='train')
# plt.scatter(x_val, y_val, c='red', label='validation')
# plt.legend()
# plt.savefig("../img/nn_mlp1.png")


#build the model
"""
X = [
"""
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name = 'X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_output], name = 'Y')

w_h = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_input, layer1_neurons], minval=-1, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32))
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, layer1_neurons], dtype=tf.float32))
h = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w_h) + b_h)

w_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([layer1_neurons, 1], minval=-1, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32))
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1], dtype=tf.float32))
model = tf.matmul(h, w_o) + b_o

train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(tf.nn.l2_loss(model - Y))
tf.nn.l2_loss(model - Y)

#output = sum((model - Y) ** 2)/2
output = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(model - Y))/2

#launch the session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

errors = []
for i in range(numEpochs):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, len(x_train), batchSize), range(batchSize, len(x_train), batchSize)):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: x_train[start:end], Y: y_train[start:end]})
    cost = sess.run(tf.nn.l2_loss(model - y_val), feed_dict={X: x_val})
    errors.append(cost)
    if i%100 == 0: print("epoch %d, cost = %g" % (i,cost))
```